# Extract view properties in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two Text views that have the same properties. Is it possible to extract these properties to avoid code duplication? Example:

Instead of this:

```
Text("some text")
.gesture(DragGesture()
        .onChanged { value in
            self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: self.showAnswer ? -1 * value.translation.height : value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
        }
        .onEnded { value in
            self.currentPosition = CGSize.zero
            print(self.newPosition.width)
            self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
        })
```

I'd like it to be like that:

```
Text("some text").gesture(extractedMethodNameHere())
```

or that (not sure what is possible in Swift)

```
Text("some text").extractedMethodNameHere()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function or a computed property for returning your gesture (as implied from your last snippets)

```
var drag: some Gesture {
    DragGesture()
    .onChanged { value in
        self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: self.showAnswer ? -1 * value.translation.height : value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
    }
    .onEnded { value in
        self.currentPosition = CGSize.zero
        print(self.newPosition.width)
        self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
    }
}
```

and then

```
Text("some text").gesture(drag)
```

Comment: I tried that but I did drag() and compiler would cry. Xcode would not be specific about the problem, instead highlighting random line.Your solution is great. Thank you

Comment: btw is it possible to do the same thing for multiple properties?

Comment: Sure. Also, here are some articles about [views as properties](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/views-as-properties), [view composition](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/view-composition) & [custom modifiers](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/custom-modifiers) that may help you on this subject.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Three Ways To Do The Same Job](https://github.com/kieranb662/ToolsForSwiftUI) for ways to share data and reuse code between views. Also [Interact](https://github.com/kieranb662/Interact) is a library that has a lot of examples of how to create reusable `ViewModifier`'s.